# Docker - remove all but last N images

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a small script that removes all docker images besides a small "cache" of N last images (for rolling back to one of the last working versions).

Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `tail` command to accomplish this.

Let's say you only want to keep the most recent 5 images. You can tell `tail` to show you the list starting with the nth line. For 5 images, you would want tail to start on the 6th line:

```
tail -n +6
```

Pair this with docker to show a list of your image IDs, which are sorted by most recent, by default.

```
docker images -q | tail -n +6
```

You can pass all of that to the remove images command. This assumes you're using the bash shell; if you use a csh-derived shell, you may need different syntax.

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q | tail -n +6)
```

Comment: If I have 2 docker containers and worked / redeployed on one more then 5 times I will remove the second app image right?

Comment: The command shown in the answer will operate on the global list of images, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to accepted answer but without the `-n`, use `head` :

```
docker rmi $(docker images -aq | head -N)
```

E.g. if N==6:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -aq | head -6)
```